# Restrict CSS to apply in which DIV

Tags: html, css, iframe

My project is in AngularJS and I have functionality in my project that outside mail can preview from my mail application. Now, i am using iFrame to preview this mail. But after updating chrome browser, the page is blinking too much because of iFrame and also want to remove this iFrame because of iFrame is now deprecated.

But there is one problem after removing iFrame. In my outside mail, which contain also CSS in it. now if i use DIV instead of iFrame than that CSS is also apply to my template and change design of my template.

So, please give me solution of alternative of iFrame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior you described is expected. The only real alternative for CSS isolation would be using the shadow DOM, although browser support is poor.

Comment: Can you give me exact example for this @sebastian

Comment: [https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/shadowdom/](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/shadowdom/)